# What is the basis of $\lambda=4$ for this matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A-4I=  \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
     -3&2&0 \\
     2&-2&\sqrt2 \\
     0&\sqrt2&-3
  \end{array}\right) 
$$

From my calculations it seems that $x_1,x_2 \text{ and }x_3$ are all leading variables. However, my teacher expressed the basis in terms of $x_3$. What I know is that we can't express a basis in terms of leading variables, we can only in terms of free variables. Any help please?

The reduced form is:
$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
     1&0&0 \\
     0&1&0 \\
     0&0&1
  \end{array}\right) $

So all three are linearly independent, right?

How am I supposed to construct the eigenspace of this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to happen here. In your first equation, there is a $\lambda$ on the left, but not on the right...

Comment: @J.M.it's not on the right, because $\lambda$ was 4 and I already subtracted it.

Comment: Um, you can't. You must have made an arithmetic error somewhere. (And, on the left, do you want $A-4I$?)

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, it's -4I. I corrected it. I'm trying to re-reduce it

Comment: @DavidMitra How do you know there should be an error?

Comment: @andrew Because, if there weren't, then you wouldn't have obtained $I$ as the echelon form.

Comment: @DavidMitra oh, I computed the reduced row echelon form. So I should go only with the row echelon. Right?

Comment: I get $\left[\matrix{-3&2&0\cr 0&-2&3\sqrt2\cr 0&0&0} \right]$ as a reduced form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that $\lambda=4$ is, indeed, an eigenvalue, then you would know the null space of the matrix  $A-4I$ is non-trivial. There is a non-zero vector $\bf x$ with $(A-4I){\bf x}=\bf 0$.

Now the claimed reduced form of $A-4I$ clearly has a trivial null space. What a quandry...

We can say:

Either $\lambda=4$ is not an eigenvalue

or you made an arithmetic mistake in deriving the reduced form.

You need to check what's wrong.  Is $4$ really an eigenvalue?  If so, then you need to redo your reduction.

(I did it and obtained  $\left[\matrix{-3&2&0\cr 0&-2&3\sqrt2\cr 0&0&0} \right]$, which has non-trivial solutions.)

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
     -3&2&0 \\
     2&-2&\sqrt2 \\
     0&\sqrt2&-3
  \end{array}\right) $

$\frac{2}{3}R_1+R_2$->$R_2$
$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
     -3&2&0 \\
     0&-4&\sqrt2 \\
     0&\sqrt2&-3
  \end{array}\right) $
$\frac{\sqrt2}{4}R_2+R_3$->$R_3$
$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
     -3&2&0 \\
     0&-4&\sqrt2 \\
     0&0&\frac{-5}{2}  \end{array}\right)$
This is what I get, I can't find the error

Comment: ${2\over 3}R_1=[ -2\ \ {4\over 3}\ \ 0] $; ${2\over3}R_1+R_2 =[ 0\ \ -{2\over3}\ \ \sqrt2]$.